# aptdaemon simulation not updating dependencies

Tags: apt, python, aptdaemon

I started playing with `aptdaemon` on Ubuntu 13.10 recently, and I'm baffled. Calling simulate() on a transaction doesn't update the dependencies list. Debug from `aptd` shows that several events are being emitted, including a PropertyChanged event for Dependencies, but my handler is not called. Here's some code that demonstrates the problem:

```
import aptdaemon.client

def printcall(*args, **kwargs):
    print("call(*%r, **%r)" % (args, kwargs))

client = aptdaemon.client.AptClient()
# I have make installed, but not abiword.
txn = client.install_packages(["make", "abiword"])
txn.connect("dependencies-changed", printcall)
txn.simulate()

print(txn.dependencies)
print(txn.packages)
```

For me, it prints an empty dependencies list (actually, a single list containing 6 empty lists), whereas running `apt-get install abiword` from the command-line comes up with several dependencies. Also, the `dependencies-changed` event is never fired:

```
dbus.Struct((dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))), signature=None, variant_level=1)
dbus.Struct((dbus.Array([dbus.String(u'make'), dbus.String(u'abiword')], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s')), dbus.Array([], signature=dbus.Signature('s'))), signature=None, variant_level=1)
```

Is this a bug, or am I missing something (like an event loop)?﻿

Comment: If you want the event fired you need to use [AptTransaction](http://pythonhosted.org/aptdaemon/aptdaemon.client.html#aptdaemon.client.AptTransaction) instead, in the way `aptdaemon.client.AptTransaction(txn.tid)`